# Passing Unix Like Path: Why This Java Code Working on Windows Machine

Tags: java, path, file-handling

I am confused with a piece of code which is by the way working, but my question is why it is working? Have a look at below code

```
public String GetQuery(int QueryIndex) throws IOException {
        String realPath = (FileHelper.class.getResource("FileHelper.class")).toString().replace("lib/FileHelper.class", "conf/").replace("file:/", "").replace("%20", " ");

        //--->Printing value of realPath
        System.out.println(realPath);
        
        //-->Creating an object of file but adding Slash before path
        //--->Works with both Widnows and Linux machine for some reason.
        File QueryFile = new File("/"+realPath + "cygnus.dll");

        BufferedReader brReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(QueryFile));
        String TempContent;
        while ((TempContent = brReader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (TempContent.split(Config.COLSEP)[0].equals("Query"+QueryIndex)) {
                brReader.close();
                return TempContent.replace("Query"+QueryIndex+Config.COLSEP, "");
            }
        }
        brReader.close();
        return TempContent;
    }
```

**Console Output of System.out.println(realPath)**

```
D:/eclipse/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/cygnus/WEB-INF/classes/com/technobee/cygnus/conf/
```

**Complete path of file passed in File constructor**

```
/D:/eclipse/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/cygnus/WEB-INF/classes/com/technobee/cygnus/conf/cygnus.dll
```

Now we can see that the we have this slash before the path and the functionality is still working. So is this an expected behavior?

Comment: AFAIK, this is allowed by the Windows file APIs (at least `/` as path separators, not 100% sure about the starting `/`), so it will work for Java as well.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, thanks for your response. One more thing does this approach works with every version of windows or from windows 10 onwards only? I am asking so that I can put necessary conditions on the basis of OS versions.

Comment: As far as I know, this has been the behaviour at least since Windows NT 3 back in the '90s. However, why not just use the appropriate APIs from `Path`/`Paths` to construct paths instead? As an aside, relying on `getResource` is a bad idea, because resources are things on the classpath, which not necessarily means they are on the file system, they could also be in a WAR or JAR file, in which case your trick will not work. Also, as far as I can tell, there should be no need to prefix it with `/`, because if you'd run this on Linux, if you obtain a valid path this way, it would already have that.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, this is a legacy code I am not planning to change it in code level. The FileHelper.class in getResource is a part of this project and in same directory where this function is written. On linux machine or Docker container If I don't add this / as prefix, it throws an file not found exception. The code is working fine on both envrionment when I prefix this path with /. As you suggested I also once though to use modern APIs but since the code is not modular, I might need to make the same changes in several places.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, I am assinged with a task to containerize this application using docker + kubernetes. So, for now I am planning to stick to that task only. I don't want to break anything by doing some voluntary code changes which I am not asked to do. `"A son asked his father (a programmer) why the sun rises in the east, and sets in the west. His response? It works, don’t touch!"` :-P :-D

Answer (score 1):

The code looks very brittle and you should fix it rather than passing on the hack especially if you have other places to change in similar manner. The technique will only work if your classes / resources are found in a file system and you use `File`.

If you deployed to app server with war/jar rather than exploded filesystem, the path returned by returned by `getResource()` cannot be interpreted correctly with `File` or `Path` as it will contain extra parts for the URI such as "jar:" and "!" for paths inside an archive.

Instead, its very easy fix to switch to properties for the locations / other resources to read, or you can locate the resource using `InputStream / getResourceAsStream` with some String manipulation based upon the package name of the search class `FileHelper.class.getPackageName()`, leading to:

```
 InputStream in = FileHelper.class.getResourceAsStream("/packagea/packageb/conf/cygnus.dll")`.
```

On Windows, `File` resolves paths like `"/C:/abc"` to be same as `new File("C:\\abc")`. However the same trick with `Path.of("/C:/abc")` fails:

```
Exception java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 2: /C:/abc
```

Comment: this is a legacy code already working in an organisation with more than 300 users. I am assinged with a task to containerize this application using docker. So, for now I am planning to stick to that task only. I don't want to break anything by doing some voluntary code changes which I am not asked to do. Moreover, I already discussed this code thing, but client is not ready to extend the deadline.

Answer (score 0):

`/` denotes the file root (on any sensible platform), so doing `/somePath/someOtherPath` on windows assumes that you mean `C:\somePath\someOtherPath`. If you specify another drive after the /, that drive gets used instead.

Comment: Small point:  `/somePath/someOtherPath` on windows assumes that you mean same as `new File("\\somePath\\someOtherPath")`, and is resolved with current drive of the JVM (not necessarily C:).

Comment: Exactly, the subsequent element after the initial slash is specifying a drive, so _File_ is able to derive the value correctly.

Comment: @DuncG, will the _"C:"_ be skipped over, if an initial slash is given? I'm using a Linux system, and cannot test this.

Comment: BTW I'd never use "/C:" as a path and am surprised it works - `Path` seems to have right behaviour by reporting exception. However, for `File` at least, the drive letter after slash isn't skipped so these expressions: `new File("/C:/abc").equals(new File("C:\\abc")) `  and `new File("/abc").equals(new File("\\abc"))` are true. If I had started JVM from F: drive, a slash without drive does not contain a drive letter but resolves with f: when accessing files. So this is true as well `new File("/abc").getAbsoluteFile().equals(new File("F:\\abc"))`.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... Now we can see that the we have this slash before the path and the functionality is still working. So is this an expected behavior?"*

A system *[path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing))* is just a notation—it's not a syntax.

There is not a standardization for a notation—as the notation is, in and of itself, the standard.

There is an RFC for the *file URI scheme*, which will define the grammar of its *path* element.
*[RFC 8089 – The "file" URI Scheme](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8089)*.

From here, we can at least see what is used by an abstraction that encloses a *path notation*.

Here is the *[ABNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form)*, from *"Section 2, Syntax"*,

```
file-URI       = file-scheme ":" file-hier-part
file-scheme    = "file"
file-hier-part = ( "//" auth-path )
               / local-path
auth-path      = [ file-auth ] path-absolute
local-path     = path-absolute
file-auth      = "localhost"
               / host
```

And, *path-absolute*, as inherited by *[RFC 3986](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986)*, under *"Section 3.3, Path"*,

```
path-absolute = "/" [ segment-nz *( "/" segment ) ]
segment       = *pchar
segment-nz    = 1*pchar
pchar         = unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"
```

It would appear that it is simply a forward-slash delimited set of values, with a required forward-slash at the start.

So, you should expect to see different results from different applications that are attempting to derive data via a provided path notation.

The syntactic value of the path is left to the resolving program, or procedure, as it is not contained within the string, and is just a notation.

This is similar to why some applications will allow for interchangeable forward and backward slashes—e.g., *"C:/value"*, and *"C:\value"* both work—and others will throw an error.